# Is this an abuse or misuse of typedef enum (using with UITableView with static content)

Tags: objective-c, ios, enums, struct, typedef

Sometimes I need to make a `UITableView` that resembles a menu and has rows that are known before compiling. I typically do this:

```
typedef enum {
    PEPSI_SODA,
    COKE_SODA,
    DRPEPPER_SODA,
    DIET_SODA,
    COUNT_SODA
} SODAS;
```

I then return `COUNT_SODA` for the `numberOfRowsInSection` and a `switch (indexPath.row) { case PEPSI_SODA: cell.textLabel.text = @"Pepsi" break; }` for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Is this a "proper" use of `typedef enum` or is there a better way to approach these types of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some type of UITableViewController subclass that you can pass a dictionary on the constructor. That way you can always reuse the same class in your projects. Your method is not reusable and produces a lot of effort to extend since you have to change things in various places to add a row.

Comment: Both answers are good, but this one was a little more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It should safely work. However, I would prefer the use of dictionaries, there you could bind the data together and you would be more flixible.